# OpenLayers: How to detect the map view is completely loaded?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm implementing map exporting functionality using OpenLayers 3.

But there is one problem: one cannot determine whether the map view is completely loaded or a few tiles is missing yet.

It seems there is no such API or event. The close one is tileloadstart - tileloadend pair. But OpenLayers loads tiles asynchronously, and before the tile is actually loading the tileloadstart is not fired - that is, a tile that is queued in the tile queue does not fire the event before actually loading.

Hot can I detect the map view is completely loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually implemented the export function successfully. Below is the rough explanation.

1. Register `tileloadstart`, `tileloadend`, `tileloaderror` event handlers on the `ol.source`s using `ol.source.on()`, and start managing the tile load count.
2. Register `postcompose` event handlers on the `ol.Map` using `ol.Map.once()`.
3. call `ol.Map.renderSync()`. This triggers the tile loading, so from now if there is no tile loading, it will mean that all tile have been loaded.
4. On `postcompose` event handler, capture the map content from `event.context` using `event.context.canvas.toDataURL()`, and register postrender function using `event.frameState.postRenderFunctions.push()` (a bit hacky).
5. On the registered postrender function, check the tile load count (which can be managed by the `tileload*` event handlers). If the count is not zero, abandon the captured content. Else, the capture is done.
6. On `tileloadend` and `tileloaderror`, if the tile load count becomes zero, retry from the step 3 above.

Comment: I second the above comment. A code example would be great.

Answer (score 16):

**postrender** event seems to do the trick, like this:

```
map.once('postrender', function(event) {
    doyourmagic();
});
```

Works at least from OpenLayers 3.8.2. There is fine answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061221/ensuring-all-tiles-are-loaded-in-open-layers-3-xyz-source) about the subject.

Comment: keep in mind this will also be triggered every time the map moves.

Comment: If you use `once` like this example does it will only be triggered once whereas `map.on('postrender'...` would trigger every time the map moves until it's taken off with `un`

Answer (score 4):

[Meanwhile](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/8532), OpenLayers provides a [much sought after](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6447) `rendercomplete` event which may be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Basically to make sure everything is rendered on your map you need to listen for loadend events for each layer you have on the map. For wms and wfs layers this is clear and I guess you know how to do it.
For the tile layers , check this example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/tile-load-events.html)

Comment: tileload* events do not work for this problem. Since the tile queue manager queues the tiles asynchronously for loading, event if there is no tile loading it does not necessarily mean that all tiles are loaded.